# Как сделать наслоение элементов экрана

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент WebView, растянутый на весь экран, и есть кнопка, которую надо сделать прозрачной и разместить в верхнем правом углу. Кнопка, естественно, частично перекрывает WebView и должна обработать нажатие. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте FrameLayout, в нем элементы можно накладывать друг на друга.
Добавьте WebView в цент поставьте размер в match_parent 
Затем в тот же FrameLayout добавьте в нужный сектор кнопку. На свое усмотрение 
задайте параметры layout:margin чтобы более менее нормально располагалась.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:visibility="visible"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:layout_marginRight="33dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню, что прозрачной кнопка становится после добавления

android:alpha="NNN", где "NNN" число от 0 до 1 (степень прозрачности).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Добавления пишите в комментариях к ответу пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать)

Comment: Я считаю, что лучше не комментарием к ответу, а просто предложить правку к этому ответу. Только код отформатируйте как код  с помощью Ctrl+K.