# Как наложить окна темного фильтра?

Tags: android

Как наложить окна темного фильтра, чтобы получить эффект ночного режима ?
Нужно добиться вот такого же эффекта
[image: Нужно сделать такой же эффект]

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, куда наложить, какие варианты использованы были и что именно неполучилось. А то есть риск что ответы будут в стиле:  "сверху" или "очень аккуратно чтобы не разбить стекло".

Comment: Были варианты использовать диалоговое окно, но сообщение по середине все портило, подсказали что на подобии такого приложения,было использовано наложение окон темного фильтра

Comment: С окнами поверх это сложно, но возможно. Если затенить картинку без необходимости обрабатывать касания - делайте. Если нужно пробиться через это окно к  элементам активити и обрабатывать касания - тут сложности будут с реализацией пропуска касаний через такой импровизированный фильтр. А еще сложнее будет читать такой код через пару тройку недель, когда он немного подзабудется.

Comment: Если все же есть желание выводить что-то поверх, то вот вариант:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0.

Comment: И все же это не совсем то что нужно:(

Comment: В примере делали с кнопкой наложение. Можно таким же образом растянуть кнопку на все окно, снести напрочь на ней текст, сделать ее нужной прозрачности и при необходимости делать видимой.

Comment: Тогда напишите что у вас НЕПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ и выложите код в котором ошибка и вам вероянее всего подскажут как исправить. Ведь реализаций масса, но какую выбрать - зависит от задачи которую нужно выполнить. Писать за вас ваш код никто не будет, такие вопросы просто удаляются. Подсказать или подправить что-то в вашем коде - это возможно.

Comment: Код который Вы указали как ответ помог в решении моей проблемы, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

Добавить в манифест разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

А в коде уже юзать нужно:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value);
```

Где в аргумент `value`можно установить значение в рамках от 0 до 255.

Можно и средствами `WindowManager`:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = i;//где i принимает значения от 0,0F до 1,0F
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```